# Raw hash displaying in my view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this controller with a hash in the `index`.

**suggestions_controller.rb**

```
class SuggestionsController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @mercs = {
            'Proxy' => './mercs/proxy.png',
            'Arty' => './mercs/arty.png',
            'Aura' => './mercs/aura.png'
        }
    end
end
```

When I transfer it to my view,

**index.html.erb**

```
<div class="merc-list">
    <%= @mercs.each do |merc, img| %>
        <div class="merc">
        </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

my view displays the raw hash:

[image: Problem]

I also tried with a regular array (with no hash), and it displays the raw array in my view.

Comment: oowowaee answered my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <%= @mercs.each do |merc, img| %>
```

should be

```
    <% @mercs.each do |merc, img| %>
```